# Can't insert string into MySQL when using UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I want to insert some data, which I got from Google Translate. For example:
http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=auto&tl=fa&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=3&uptl=fa&alttl=en&sc=1&text=hello

After I receive the result, I want to insert it into a MySQL table. So I wrote the following code:

```
$link     = "http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=auto&tl=fa&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=3&uptl=fa&alttl=en&sc=1&text=";

$server   = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "AliAhmadi";
$password = "AliAhmadi";
$database = "AliAhmadi";

$conn     = mysql_pconnect($server, $username, $password);
if (!$conn)
     die("Bye Bye");
mysql_select_db($database, $conn);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
$ch       = curl_init();
$url          = $link."hello";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$WebContent   = curl_exec($ch);
$update_query = 'update `en_db` SET `meaning`="'.mysql_real_escape_string($WebContent).'" where `id`=1';
mysql_query($update_query,$conn);
mysql_close($conn);
```

Google sent the following text file:

```
[[["سلام", "hello", "", ""]], [["interjection", ["سلام", "هالو", "الو"], [["سلام", ["hello", "hi", "aloha", "all hail"]], ["هالو", ["hallo", "hello", "halloo"]], ["الو", ["hello"]]]]], "en", , [["سلام", [5], 0, 0, 1000, 0, 1, 0]], [["hello", 4, , , ""], ["hello", 5, [["سلام", 1000, 0, 0], ["خوش", 0, 0, 0], ["میهمان گرامی", 0, 0, 0], ["خوش آمدید", 0, 0, 0], ["درود کاربر", 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 5]], "hello"]], , , [["en"]], 74]
```

But in table only the first part of the string is saved:

```
[[["
```

I think the problem comes from unicode, because when I comment `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);` it will save something in the table, but something that looks like

```
[[["Èå","to","",""]],[["preposition",["Èå","ÈÑÇ\u06CC","ÏÑ","ÏÑ ÈÑÇÈÑ","\u06CCÔ","Óæ\u06CC","äÒÏ","ØÑÝ","ÈÓæ\u06CC","ÊÇ äÓÈÊ Èå","ÈÑ ÍÓÈ","ÈØÑÝ","ÑæÈØÑÝ"],[["Èå",["to","into","in","on","at","against"]],["ÈÑÇ\u06CC",["for","to","on","for the sake","toward","in order that"]],["ÏÑ",["at","to","about","unto"]],["ÏÑ ÈÑÇÈÑ",["against","versus","to","for","unto"]],["\u06CCÔ",["before","to","with","unto"]],["Óæ\u06CC",["to","unto"]],["äÒÏ",["to","near","about"]],["ØÑÝ",["towards","to"]],["ÈÓæ\u06CC",["toward","to","into","off","unto","at"]],["ÊÇ äÓÈÊ Èå",["to","unto"]],["ÈÑ ÍÓÈ",["according to","in","at","to"]],["ÈØÑÝ",["toward","at","unto","to","in","into"]],["ÑæÈØÑÝ",["unto","to"]]]],["",["ÚáÇãÊ ãÕÏÑ Çäá\u06CCÓ\u06CC ÇÓÊ"],[["ÚáÇãÊ ãÕÏÑ Çäá\u06CCÓ\u06CC ÇÓÊ",["to"]]]]],"en",,[["Èå",[5],0,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["to",4,,,""],["to",5,[["Èå",1000,0,0],["ÈÑÇ\u06CC",0,0,0],["ÊÇ",0,0,0],["ÑÇ Èå",0,0,0],["Èå ãäÙæÑ",0,0,0]],[[0,2]],"to"]],,,,5]
```

What is the unicode of what google translator returns? And where is my problem with this code? I changed Collation between utf8_unicode_ci, utf8_general_ci and utf8_presian_ci but this problem happened again.

Comment: have you tried adding `SET NAMES utf8;` before any other sql statements? Don't trust `mysql_` functions :)

Comment: yes,I test it,but it wasn't work

Comment: Could you add your table creation definition as well? Your table fields should be utf8 as well

Comment: It looks like you're trying to store Google Translate's result data, which is a JSON string, into your table without modifying it.  You definitely want to use bind variables for this.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @Jack: that's not right at all. `mysql_set_charset` is the correct thing to do as it both executes `SET NAMES` and remembers the charset so that `mysql_real_escape_string` works correctly for the given charset. If you only do `SET NAMES`, and you are unlucky enough to be using an East Asian charset then you've got yourself an SQL injection security hole.

Comment: @bobince hmm, you're probably right; i'm used to PDO doing that automatically for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your `en_db.meaning` column is defined as the default collation `latin1_swedish_ci`. This uses the ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) encoding, which cannot store Arabic characters.

(When you remove the `mysql_set_charset` call, MySQL misinterprets your UTF-8 Arabic as Latin characters, which do fit in that column, but just look completely wrong.)

Make sure when you create the table you specify a collation that uses UTF-8, for example `CREATE TABLE en_db (...) COLLATE utf8_general_ci` or in general `(...) CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4` for astral plane support if available).

You can change the collation of an existing table and all the text columns in it with `ALTER TABLE en_db CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8`, though if you've already got non-ASCII characters in it they are likely to be wrong either way.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
//Set Beginning of php code:
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

//then create the connection 
$CNN=mysql_connect("localhost","usr_urdu","123") or die('Unable to Connect');
$DB=mysql_select_db('db_urdu',$CNN)or die('Unable to select DB');
```